# Coordinates transformation

Tags: qgis, r, coordinate-system

I have the following data base with information about rainfall for a set of meteorological stations:

```
  year  station latitude longitude depto municipio       date rainfall
  1990 11010010   0527 N    7632 W CHOCO     LLORO 1990-01-01     13.2
  1990 11010010   0527 N    7632 W CHOCO     LLORO 1990-01-02     83.1
  1990 11010010   0527 N    7632 W CHOCO     LLORO 1990-01-03     10.5
  1990 11010010   0527 N    7632 W CHOCO     LLORO 1990-01-04      9.1
  1990 11010010   0527 N    7632 W CHOCO     LLORO 1990-01-05      0.0
  1990 11010010   0527 N    7632 W CHOCO     LLORO 1990-01-06     10.4
```

I am trying to import this to QGIS using the "New layer from delimited text" tool, but QGIS is unable to detect the longitude and latitude even specifying the X and Y coordinates. I know these longitudes and latitudes are not the common WGS84 ones, there is a way to reproject both coordinates?

(I also use R but rgdal commands do not work with the Spatialframe).

Comment: They are probably DD MM so 5 27 N and 76 32 W.

Comment: Is this weather station in Quebec or Columbia?

Comment: Chocó is a department of Colombia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have ACSII characters in your coordinate columns (ie., "N" & "W") which is also why you have leading zeros in the latitude column. Your lat/long values do not make any sense in their current format. @mkennedy is likely correct that they are DD MM and need to be reformatted accordingly.

You could read this data into R as a flat file using read.table or read.csv, reformat the columns and then coerce into a SpatialPointsDataFrame object.

Here is an example where we reformat the DD MM coordinates and create a SpatialPointsDataFrame.

First, let's recreate your example data as a data.frame object

```
( rain <- data.frame( year = rep(1990,6), station = rep(11010010, 6),
latitude = rep("0527 N", 6), longitude = rep("7632 W", 6),
date = c("1990-01-01","1990-01-02","1990-01-03","1990-01-04","1990-01-05","1990-01-06"), 
rainfall = c(13.2,83.1,10.5,9.1,0.0,10.4) ) )
```

Here we convert the ASCII coordinates to DD, [degrees + ( minutes / 60 )]. The function substr lets us pull a fixed portion of the string and lapply takes the place of a for loop. The unlist function coerces the resulting list to a vector.

```
lat <- lapply(rain$latitude, FUN = function(x) {
      c(as.numeric(substr(x, 2, 2)),
      as.numeric(substr(x, 3, 4))) } ) 
lat <- unlist(lapply(lat, FUN= function(x) { x[1] + ( x[2] / 60 ) } ))

long <- lapply( rain$longitude, FUN = function(x) {
      c(as.numeric(substr(x, 1, 2)),
      as.numeric(substr(x, 3, 4))) } )    
long <- unlist(lapply(long, FUN= function(x) { x[1] + ( x[2] / 60 ) } ))
```

Here we add the lat, long vectors to the rain data.frame (creating a new data.frame, rain.sp) and coerce to sp object.

```
library(sp)
rain.sp <- data.frame(rain, lat=lat, long=long * -1)
coordinates(rain.sp) <- ~long+lat
class(rain.sp)
```

However, one thing that I notice is that since your data is in long format you have repeated measurements of rainfall for a given station. With a direct conversion of the data you will end up with a replicated point location for each date measurement, which is bad practice and will cause considerable issues down the road. To account for this we can simply transpose the data into a long format and then apply the above method.

Here we use the spread function in the tidyr library to transpose the data.frame to a long format where each date measurement becomes a column and each station becomes a single observation (line).

```
library(tidyr)
( rain <- spread(rain, date, rainfall) )
```

Now we can repeat the above procedure and end up with a spatial object, representing single stations with rain measurements for each date, in columns.

```
# Convert coordinates to DD, degrees + ( minutes / 60 )
lat <- lapply(rain$latitude, FUN = function(x) {
      c(as.numeric(substr(x, 2, 2)),
      as.numeric(substr(x, 3, 4))) } ) 
lat <- unlist(lapply(lat, FUN= function(x) { x[1] + ( x[2] / 60 ) } ))  
long <- lapply( rain$longitude, FUN = function(x) {
      c(as.numeric(substr(x, 1, 2)),
      as.numeric(substr(x, 3, 4))) } )    
long <- unlist(lapply(long, FUN= function(x) { x[1] + ( x[2] / 60 ) } ))

# Add lat/long data to data.frame and coerce to sp object
library(sp)
rain.sp <- data.frame(rain, lat=lat, long=long * -1)
coordinates(rain.sp) <- ~long+lat

class(rain.sp)
str(rain.sp@data)  
rain.sp@data
```

Comment: you do not really need `lapply` and could do: `lat <- as.numeric(substr(rain$latitude, 1, 2)) + as.numeric(substr(rain$latitude, 3, 4))/60`

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to reformat the data in the table before feeding it to QGIS, perhaps into two new columns called `lat` and `long`, and seeing that these are in signed decimal degrees. If the data are indeed in DDMM, your first line should be converted to:

```
0527 N  7632 W  ---->  5.45  -76.533
```